# Render show view in a partial - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

So I have a sidebar in my rails application. Basically, I have a grid full of images. When someone clicks on an image in the grid, I basically want the show view to be displayed in the sidebar. I'm clueless on how to do this.

I've tried copying and pasting the show view's html and erb into my `_sidebar.html.erb` partial. But I get variable errors. My partial is located in my layout folder. But I can move it if needed.

Here is an image of the application for a better idea of what I'm talking about.

[image: This is what my app looks like. The gray part is the sidebar partial.]

Comment: I suggest reading and learning about Rails' AJAX and JS views convention. There are many ways to do what you're wanting to do, so you'll need to learn the HOW and then implement it. Come back with you have a code-specific question or problem and we'll help.  Read these: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html and https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it:

---

1) Include the `sidebar` [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) in your *layout*:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= render "shared/sidebar" %>
```

This calls the `_sidebar.html.erb` partial in `/app/views/shared`:

---

2) Populate the "default" sidebar partial:

```
#app/views/shared/_sidebar.html.erb
...
```

The important thing to note here is that partials should ***never*** have `@instance` variables inside.

Partials have [`locals`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), which you can pass with the following command:

```
<%= render "shared/sidebar", locals: { variable: "value" } %>
```

*Partials* are meant to run on *any* part of your web application, and since `@instance` variables are present for a single "instance" of an object (IE `@post` won't be available in `/users`), you can ensure partials are always populated by passing local variables to them.

This is why you received errors when copying your `post#show` code to your `sidebar` partial -- the instance variables present for the `show` action will not be present in other parts of the app.

---

3) Use JS to pull image *objects*

> When someone clicks on an image in the grid, I basically want the show view to be displayed in the sidebar.

You need to be more specific - do you *really* want the "show" action to appear, or do you want parts of its functionality?

Either way, you'll be best using JS & ajax to pull the data:

```
#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
   layout Proc.new { |controller| !controller.request.xhr? }
end

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", "img", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
      $(".sidebar .image").html(data);
   });
});
```

This will take the rendered `images#show` action (without layout), and append it to your *sidebar* partial. This is what you asked for - I can change it if required.

Comment: HI Rich! So far, I have been able to get the sidebar to render post views correctly. By using '<%= render "layouts/sidebar", :post => @post %>' . So my partial has erb like '<%= post.title %>' for example and that works correctly. I tried adding the javascript you gave me as well as the controller code but it doesn't seem to be working. I wasn't sure where to put the controller code so I put it under the show method and removed "layout" because it was giving me an error. Any suggestions? Here is the github link https://github.com/mattietea/musicapp. Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need to specify "local".

<%= render "shared/sidebar", variable: "value" %> works

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that your model is called "Image".

In your "images/show.html.erb":

```
# This is a handy shortcut that will call the 'images/_image' partial. 
# Those two lines are exactly the same. 
<%= render @image %>
<%= render "images/image", image: @image %>
```

In your "_sidebar.html.erb":

```
<div id="sidebar-img"></div>
```

In your "images/_image.html.erb":

```
 # Code displaying your image, don't use any global variable.
 # 'image' is the name of the local variable
```

In your grid:

```
 # remote: true allows you to do an AJAX call
 <%= link_to image, remote: true do %> 
   # Something like that, I don't know your code
   <%= image_tag image.url %>
 <% end %>
```

Create "images/show.js.erb", when clicking on a 'remote :true' link it will call this file.

```
 # set @image to Image.find(params[:id]) in your controller
 $("#sidebar-img").html("<%= render @image %>");
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed answer!  I have a couple questions. 

Firstly, in my posts/show.html.erb. Why would I want to render @post? It's the partial that has my for loop to create the posts in my grid.When I try to add '<%= render @post %>' I get an error that says "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" . In my show controller I added '@post = Post.find(params[:id]). 
Secondly, for my grid link_to. Can I just do '<%= link_to 'Show', post, remote: true %>' or is that not ok?
Thank you so much for the help. 
If it's too much explaining, I understand. Ill keep reading around haha.

Comment: By post, you mean what I called image right?

If you want to render multiple posts, you shouln't do it in your posts#show but in your posts#index for instance. 
The partial _post.html.erb should not contain a loop, it should just render the post itself. If you want to render several posts, just use:
render \@posts. \@posts being an 'array' of posts, it will call _post.html.erb for each post in the array.  

<%= link_to 'Show', post, remote: true %>' is ok if you have a posts/show.js.erb.